# How to add two VLANs for DHCP Pool

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, wireless, dhcp

Currently one of my customer has DHCP pool created in Cisco Switch and ip address range is 192.168.25.0/24 (This is a VLAN). Now they have 230 devices and They are going to increase device count by 100. DCHP assigned for Wireless network and  cisco 2500 Wireless controller also available.

I cannot change subnet and increased usable IP addresses count because there are many dependencies.

What is possibility of Adding two VLANs to one DHCP Pool?
If it is possible, How do we add?
What kind of changes necessary from wireless controller?

Or what is solution for this issue?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Questions about protocols above layer 4 are off limits here, however, as a very basic explanation on a layer 2 and layer 3 level, you cannot have multiple VLANs using the same DHCP pool (same subnet). Each VLAN would need a separate DHCP pool (separate subnet) to assign addresses from.

For example:

```
VLAN 100: 192.168.1.0/24
VLAN 200: 192.168.2.0/24
```

Just to make something else clear, you would also not be able to increase the size of the existing network to share between the 2 VLANs, as that would also cause overlap issues.

For example, if you currently have 192.168.1.0/24 you would not be able to increase the mask to /23 and then hand out the first half for VLAN 100 and the second half for VLAN 200, as this would still create a conflict.

You could increase the mask to /23 (or larger) for the existing network to use for the existing/same VLAN, however, such as if you wanted to have 192.168.1.0/23 associated with VLAN 100.  VLAN 200 would still need its own scope, though.

Answer (score 3):

> Now they have 230 devices and They are going to increase device count by 100.

Within the same subnet? Then you'd have to supernet that subnet to e.g. 192.168.24.0/23.

> I cannot change subnet and increased usable IP addresses count because there are many dependencies.

Adding another subnet/VLAN is a better option anyway. As Jesse's already answered, that requires a second DHCP pool as well.

> What is possibility of Adding two VLANs to one DHCP Pool?

That isn't possible. You can have multiple pools for a single VLAN but not the other way around.

> What kind of changes necessary from wireless controller?

None, if the wireless controller and network stay bridged on the already existing network/subnet and you don't need to the change the default gateway. If you need to change the default gateway to e.g. your L3 switch then that is the change to make there as well (and for the DHCP scopes).

Comment: How wifi controller knows which VLAN going to be issue ip address for devices?

Comment: If you don't reconfigure anything it'll keep connecting to the already existing subnet.

Comment: No i am asking if i add new VLAN+DHCP pool, what kind of change required from wireless controller?

Comment: Then you need to tell us what you really want to achieve... I've answered all the questions you asked.

Comment: I am creating VLANs on L3 Switch. I have no idea about wireless controller.  When i create separate DHCP pool with VLAN, How wireless controller knows new DHCP pool has been configured and when existing pool reach to maximum bindings, It should move to second pool?

Comment: If you want to relocate your Wi-Fi clients to the new VLAN - there's no hint of that in your question - then yes, you'll need to configure the wireless controller. If you add the current config and your detailed goal to your question we might be able to tell you what to do.

Comment: My question is simple. My asset manager going to purchase 100 Laptops. Currently We have 230+ Laptops and all are connected to same wifi ssid. currently We have cisco Wifi controller 2500 and 3650 Cisco Switch. DHCP pool created in Cisco Switch and VLAN has been added. IP address of VLAN is 192.168.25.0/24. I cannot expand this range because of dependencies. Therefore next option is  creating second VLAN and Assigned it second DHCP pool. I have zero idea about wireless controller. I want to know, what kind of configuration should i have to do in wireless controller, when adding DHCP pool

Answer (score 2):

you could add a second range to another vlan. If the switch is a layer 3 switch, it shouldn't be a problem to connect to eachother. If not, a downtime is necessary to adapt the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

There is one option available.  Create a new VLAN and create new DHCP scope for this VLAN

Assuming you created new VLAN as VLAN 20

`Switch (config)#ip dhcp pool Vlan20`

`Switch(config)#network 192.168.X.X 0.0.255.255`

`Switch (config)# default-router ip 192.168.1.1`

`Switch (config)#dns-server 8.8.8.8`

Also create the same VLAN 20 on downstream access switches, and connect newly deployed 100 system to this VLAN 20 and then create an access-list on L3 switch to provide access among VLAN as per business requirements.

Comment: You need to fix your answer or remove it. A few of your commands you gave are wrong for defining a DHCP pools, as well as there being multiple syntax errors that could potentially break other communications flowing through the switch or at least cause errors while entering the commands.

Comment: Yes but it’s still not correct. You can’t define the default gateway arbitrarily because it effects everything the switch does.  It also has nothing to do with DHCP.